# android animation in different screen sizes

Tags: android, animation, screen-size

I am animating a layout which contains a button and a spinner using objectAnimator.In my mobile the layout moves to top.But when I tried to run the app in another mobile with larger screens size,it moved to half the screen.How can I get the  x and y axis of screen .The code is below.
MainActivity.java:

```
ObjectAnimator translate=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(relativeLayout1,"translationY",0,-174);
                   translate.setDuration(1000);
                   translate.start();
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels

Comment: isn't the top of the screen x,y = 0,0 ?

Comment: I set the value to -174.It works perfectly in my phone.I want to get the top most y axis position of any screen so that I can do -top+20 and set it to animate to that position.@NJNIiesh The code in the link you shared  gives the pixels(1080X1920)

Answer (score 1):

First, access to the screen dpi,then target yoffset = target dpi / your dpi * your yoffset